# Unterminated string error Visual Studio 2017 Installing NPM package

Tags: visual-studio, path, installation, npm-install, visual-studio-2017

I just trying to install NPM package in Blank NodeJs Application inside VisualStudio 2017 and I am getting Error:

```
 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'generator-zurb-ink.time', line 1, '
```

Anybody had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with VS2015; the length of the package path could be too long. I believe the path limit is 260 characters, so if the folder names are long or the project is nested deeply on your drive, this error can occur.

Try moving it to somewhere with a shorter path, e.g. `C:/foo/node_modules/...` and reduce folder name length where possible.